# How can I dynamically filter Low Search results?

Tags: low-search

I am getting the results I want from my Low Search Form tag but would like to filter with checkboxes in my Low Search Filter tag.  Could someone please help me with this?   Thanks

My Low Search Filter tag uses Low Options, Low List and Solspace Tag:

```
{exp:low_search:filters query="{segment_3}"}
    {exp:low_options:project}
        {options}
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="search:project[]" value="{option:value}"
            {if "{option:value}" ~ '/(^|\|)'.low_search_search:project.'($|\|)/'}checked="checked"{/if}/> 
            {option:label}
        </label>
        {/options}
    {/exp:low_options:project}

    {exp:low_list:each items="0|100:0 to 100;200|300:200 to 300;400|600:400 to 600" sep=";"}
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="range:cost[]" value="{key}" {if key == low_search_range:cost} checked{/if}>
        {val} 
    </label>
    {/exp:low_list:each}

    {exp:tag:cloud}
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tag_id[]" value="{tag_id}"{if low_search_tag_id ~ '/\b'.tag_id.'\b/'} checked{/if}>
        {tag}
    </label>
    {/exp:tag:cloud}
{/exp:low_search:filters}
```

Comment: Which issue you are facing with above code?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  When I check filter checkboxes they don't modify the query in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using form elements like checkboxes, use the [Form tag](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#form-tag) rather than the Filters tag. This will generate a `<form>` element around the checkboxes. You can then use **JavaScript** to submit the form when a checkbox is (un)checked.

Alternatively, you can use the [Filters tag](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#filters-tag) together with the (short syntax) [URL tag](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#url-tag) to create a list of **links** rather than checkbox elements, which will just generate URLs instead of a form.